# How to apply css for only second occurance

Tags: html, css

here i am trying to apply the css for only second table.

but in my web page i have 2 tables, if i apply this css for the table
both the tables are taking the css. but i want to apply the css only for the second tables.

css code:

```
body{
    background:url(aya.jpg);
}

table { 
    color: #333;
    font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    width: 640px; 
    border-collapse: 
    collapse; border-spacing: 0; 
}

td, th { 
    border: 1px solid black;
    height: 30px; 
    transition: all 0.3s;
}

th {
    background: #757575;
    font-weight: bold;
    color:white;
}

td {
    background: #FAFAFA;
    text-align: center;
}

tr:nth-child(even) td { 
    background: #F2F2F2; 
}   

tr:nth-child(odd) td { 
    background: #E6ECF2; 
}
```

html code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/common-style.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/button.css">
</head>
<body>
<center>

<table>
<tr>
    <th>One</th>
    <th>Two</th>
    <th>Three</th>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Apples</td>
    <td>Carrots</td>
    <td>Steak</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Oranges</td>
    <td>Potato</td>
    <td>Pork</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Pears</td>
    <td>Peas</td>
    <td>Chicken</td>
</tr>
</table>


<table class="obd">
<tr>
    <th>One</th>
    <th>Two</th>
    <th>Three</th>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Apples</td>
    <td>Carrots</td>
    <td>Steak</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Oranges</td>
    <td>Potato</td>
    <td>Pork</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Pears</td>
    <td>Peas</td>
    <td>Chicken</td>
</tr>
</table>



</center>
</body>
</html>
```

How can i resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change your css as

```
table.obd { 
    color: #333;
    font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    width: 640px; 
    border-collapse: 
    collapse; border-spacing: 0; 
}

table.obd td, table.obd th { 
    border: 1px solid black;
    height: 30px; 
    transition: all 0.3s;
}

table.obd th {
    background: #757575;
    font-weight: bold;
    color:white;
}

table.obd td {
    background: #FAFAFA;
    text-align: center;
}


table.obd tr:nth-child(even) td { 
    background: #F2F2F2; 
}   

table.obd tr:nth-child(odd) td { 
    background: #E6ECF2; 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

DEMO: [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/xeemez/L5vc4/1/)

> CSS  Change table to some ID:

```
body{
background:url(aya.jpg);
}
#tableSec { 
 color: #333;
 font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
 width: 640px; 
 border-collapse: 
 collapse; border-spacing: 0; 
}

#tableSec td, #tableSec th { 
 border: 1px solid black;
 height: 30px; 
 transition: all 0.3s;
}

#tableSec th {
 background: #757575;
 font-weight: bold;
 color:white;
}

#tableSec td {
 background: #FAFAFA;
 text-align: center;
}


tableSec tr:nth-child(even) td { 
background: #F2F2F2; 
}   

#tableSec tr:nth-child(odd) td { 
background: #E6ECF2; 
}
```

> In html code give desired table that ID:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/common-style.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/button.css">
</head>
<body>
<center>

<table>
<tr>
    <th>One</th>
    <th>Two</th>
    <th>Three</th>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Apples</td>
    <td>Carrots</td>
    <td>Steak</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Oranges</td>
    <td>Potato</td>
    <td>Pork</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Pears</td>
    <td>Peas</td>
    <td>Chicken</td>
</tr>
</table>


<table class="obd" id="tableSec">
<tr>
    <th>One</th>
    <th>Two</th>
    <th>Three</th>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Apples</td>
    <td>Carrots</td>
    <td>Steak</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Oranges</td>
    <td>Potato</td>
    <td>Pork</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Pears</td>
    <td>Peas</td>
    <td>Chicken</td>
</tr>
</table>



</center>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `table.obd` instead of `table` in the CSS, and change all `table tr td` related styles accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

add to the first table class .first, and second one .second

Answer (score -2):

First of all, it's bad practice to use tables in modern day web design. But if you're adament, reference the second table with .obd. I would reference with an id instead of a class though, on both tables.

Comment: Tables are fine for tabular data, which this appears to be.

Comment: I'll have to respectfully disagree on this. It's easier to write, yes,  but the table wont be rendered until all of its markup has been downloaded, whereas the individual divs will be rendered as soon as their markup is downloaded. It also adds more flexibility to styling.

Comment: @DanielSchwarz: yes, but you do not use divs to display "real" tables!

Comment: Sure. Can I ask why? I've added my reasoning, but nobody has stated what the upside to using tables is.

Comment: @DanielSchwarz Seems timely that Chris Coyier should blog about the table element. He can explain it far better than I can: http://css-tricks.com/complete-guide-table-element/